# can I wait to return my response to get an Access token?

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, angular-http-interceptors

Hello I am currently trying to get an access token through my service, however, the issue is when I don't have an access token I try to refresh the page with a special url that will create a token, unfortunately the function still runs without waiting for this url to load the new token. Is there a way to add promise or do you have a different approach to this? If you have any ideas please let me know. Thank you!!

Code:

```
app.factory('HttpInterceptor', function ($q, $window, CustomService) {
  return {
    request: function (config) {
            if(CustomService.getAccessToken() == undefined) {
                $window.location.href = CustomService.getURL();
            }
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + CustomService.getAccessToken(); // this is still undefined since window.location.href is still loading
        return $q.when(config);
    },
    responseError: function(response) {
        if(response.status == 401){
            $window.location.href = CustomService.getURL();
        }
        return $q.reject(response)
    }
  };
});

app.service('CustomService', function($location) {
    this.getAccessToken = function() {
      if(getParam('token')){
          this.token = getParam('token');
      } 
      return this.token;
    }

    this.getURL = function(){
           var redirectUrl = //adds url
        return redirectUrl;
        
    }
    
    function getParam(name) {
      var token = null;
      token = //adds token info
      return token;
    }
});
```

Comment: If the `CustomService` returns a promise, that can be used to delay. We need to see the code for the `CustomService` to see how to modify it to work with the interceptor. Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises. For more information, see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - Chaining Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises).

Comment: @georgeawg Thank you for your help with this! I added my CustomService code, I removed some information, however, the getURL I could convert to use a promise to delay is this your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `config.url` in `request` function.

- First findout the url pattern which `CustomService.getURL()` returns.
- In every request check if the `config.url` matches the `CustomService.getURL()` and the access token is empty or expired.
- If the checking `true` then proceed with `$window.location.href = CustomService.getURL();`
- If the checking is `false` then redirect to special url  `$window.location.href = CustomService.getURL();`

**Sample request Code:**

```
request: function (config) {
   if(CustomService.getAccessToken() == undefined && config.url.indexOf('oauth2')) {  
     //'oauth2' can be of any pattern
     $window.location.href = CustomService.getURL();
   }
   else{
     config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' +  CustomService.getAccessToken(); 
     // this is still undefined since window.location.href is still loading
   }

   return $q.when(config);
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried your approach and I have a question, the issue that I am running into is that when I call to $window.location.href to reload the page, how can I wait for the new page to load and retrieve the new token? it seems the request is getting call more than once and it does not give a chance for the first call to load